# Rails - Heroku images not finding right path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, path

I'm using Rails 5.2.0 and have deployed to Heroku. I have images being loaded using the following call:

`...link_to image_tag("/assets/avatar.png", class: "img-responsive")...`

on my local machine and they load properly.

The directory structure is:

```
my_project
    app
    |    assets
    |    |   images
    |    |   |    avatar.png
```

However, on Heroku, the images aren't loading. I have checked other posts but am not sure if I need to modify my Gemfile / production.rb etc. I have also tried changing the path on Heroku to

`...link_to image_tag("app/assets/avatar.png", class: "img-responsive")...`

adding the `/app` to the path but this hasn't worked either.

My question is do I need to just change the path so Heroku can find the images. If so, what does the path need to be? Where does Heroku "start" the path from when a Rails app is running?

Or is there something else that needs to be done to allow Heroku to find and load these images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be like this below

```
<%= link_to image_tag("avatar.png", class: "img-responsive"), url_path %>
```

Look the [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) for how image_tag works.

Update `production.rb` file `config.assets.compile` `false` to `true`

```
# config/environments/production.rb
...
config.assets.compile = true
...
```

Comment: This did not work. Again, the images are loading on my local, but Heroku can't find them

Comment: On the `config/environments/production.rb` check and enable this `config.assets.compile = true`, then commit/push to heroku again

Comment: It turns out that my image tag line was fine. The only thing I needed to change was the `config/environments/production.rb` and set this line: `config.assets.compile` to be true