# Images are not loading in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I pushed all my codes + images to Github and connected GitHub to heroku with automatic deploy mode turned on. When pushing codes to Heroku, everything works fine except the images are not showing.

Locally, I store my images in assets/images.

I tried git pull, git push, also heroku rake db:migrate prior to asking this.

That said, I'm a beginner, so please be kind to me :(

Comment: can you share the link of heroku app & github repo as well ?

Comment: https://github.com/cheese1884/18841884

Comment: https://sheltered-dusk-47279.herokuapp.com/

Comment: In config/production.rb you need to add the image files to the precompiled assets:
config.assets.precompile + ['your image files']

Comment: sorry, but how do i do this? In the file it's

Comment: Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )

Comment: try running heroku run rails assets:precompile

Comment: and add this line in environment/production.rb `config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif] `

Comment: heroku run rails assets:precompile
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.0.60 to 7.16.0
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help

Comment: deploying again to heroku with the line added yielded https://justpaste.it/5j50v in the logs

Comment: saw that image is uploaded to heroku, only it's not loading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails - Heroku images not finding right path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716681/rails-heroku-images-not-finding-right-path)

Comment: @songs take a look this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390777/how-add-style-background-image-in-element-div-using-asset-pipeline/36391043#36391043 and `<%= asset_path 'blabla.jpg' %>` if its localted in `assets/images`. if in folder then `<%= asset_path 'foldername/blabla.jpg' %>`

Comment: Hi @songs I have replied to a question recently about asset pipeline and sprockets, you may read here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421137/rails-5-heroku-assets-are-not-loaded-in-production-but-works-in-localhost/52423496#comment91800187_52423496

Comment: Be careful, you have your `secrets.yml` in git. Also I would move `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]` to `assets.rb` (its in `production.rb` at the moment) also change `config.assets.compile = true` to `config.assets.compile = false` then read the above link I have posted.